# How can I find a set of characters in a char array

Tags: c++, windows

I'm writing a C++ Windows httpPlatformHandler web app. The data coming in has http headers separated by \r\n. After the last header is double \r\n followed by the posted data. I need to get a pointer to the posted data.

I looked at strchr but that only looks for a single character. I need to look for "\r\n\r\n" and have a pointer to the posted data after that.

The Winsock recv function gets the data into this variable:

```
char szRecvBuffer[1024];
```

Comment: When doing stuff with strings try to use types like std::string/std::string_view. Have a look at std::string's find function it might help you too.

Comment: You want `std::getline`

Comment: What happens if the client sends more than 1024 bytes of data?

Comment: Always a good question, the receive function will return a larger number and this needs to be handled correctly. The API allows you to pass the buffer size so that won't crash but data will be lost and error handling is probably a thing.

Comment: recv is called in a loop. szRecvBuffer is appended to a string. The issue is that the posted data is Unicode while the headers are not.

Answer (score 0):

The use of string_view and find on your buffer in code :

```
#include <array>
#include <string_view>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::array<char, 1024ul> buf; // receive buffer (nice thing is a std::array will keep track of its own size)
    std::string data_to_receive{ "Hello world!\r\n\r\nData 123" };
    
    // simulate recv(ClientSocket, buf.data(), buf.size(), 0); by copying data into buf
    std::copy(data_to_receive.begin(), data_to_receive.end(), buf.begin());
    
    // this will normally be returned by receive function of your socket.
    std::size_t bytes_received = data_to_receive.length();

    // make a string_view on the buffer that spans the received data (no pointers at all)
    // this avoids looking at bytes in the buffer that are outside the received data range
    std::string_view buf_view{ buf.begin(),buf.begin() + bytes_received };
    
    // then within that view find the characters you are looking for
    auto pos = buf_view.find("\r\n\r\n");
    if (pos != std::string::npos)
    {
        std::string_view substring{ buf.begin() + pos, buf.begin() + bytes_received };
        std::cout << substring;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've never used array or string_view, I'll look into using them. What does the ul after 1024 stand for? I should mention that the posted data is Unicode and the headers are UTF8.

Comment: std array has the same performance as "C" style arrays but can passed around like objects so by (const) reference if you want to. And can easily be returned from functions as well (like any other object). Oversimplified a string_view is  a struct with a begin and end pointer into existing data. UTF8 is still byte (char) based, just don't confuse the number of bytes (length of view) with the actual number of characters.